# Active Admin form: has_many inputs in separate panels by condition

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I am trying to use active admin and formtastic to create a form where reviews of a specific type is edited on a separate panel, currently I render the panels through a .html.erb partial like this:

```
<div class="panel">
  <h3>Admin Reviews</h3>
  <div class="panel_contents">
    <div>
      <% f.has_many :reviews, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: false do |review| %>
        <% next unless review.object.reviewer_type === "Admin" %>
        <%= render partial: "admin/admin_reviews", locals: { r: review } %>
        <% review.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Delete" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <h3>Reviews</h3>
  <div class="panel_contents">
  <div>
    <% f.has_many :reviews, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: false do |review| %>
       <% next if review.object.reviewer_type === "Admin" %>
       <%= render partial: "admin/form_reviews", locals: { r: review } %>
       <% review.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Delete" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I would much rather do something like to get rid of the blank div that is generated for each review being iterated through that belongs in the other panel ([blank div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQa2j.png)):

```
<div class="panel">
  <h3>Admin Reviews</h3>
  <div class="panel_contents">
    <div>
      <% admin_reviews = Review.where(reviewer_type: "Admin") %>
      <% f.has_many admin_reviews, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |review| %>
        <%= render partial: "admin/admin_reviews", locals: { r: review } %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <h3>Reviews</h3>
  <div class="panel_contents">
  <div>
    <% reviews = Review.where.not(reviewer_type: "Admin") %>
    <% f.has_many reviews, heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |review| %>
       <%= render partial: "admin/form_reviews", locals: { r: review } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above does not work, but I hope it communicates my need for a neater solution that does not have blank divs that I am considering hiding with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="panel">
  <h3>Reviews</h3>
    <div class="panel_contents">
      <div>
        <% f.has_many :reviews, for: [:reviews, f.object.non_admin_reviews], heading: false, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |review| %>
          <%= render partial: "admin/tutors/form_tutor_reviews", locals: { r: review } %>
        <% end %>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```